# resolve for theta when using $2$ cosines

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to resolve the following equation for $\theta$ but I have been dumbstruck at how to multiply the $2$ cosines together. I understand that $\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta) = \cos(\theta)^2$ but I do not know how to handle the $90^\circ - \theta$ in the second cosine. I have asked my teachers at school about this but they do not know either. Any help? :)
$$
    \cos(\theta)\cos(\theta-90^\circ) = 0.6375/245
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Draw $\cos(\theta-90^\circ)$. What other function (you know) does it look like? The product of $\cos$ and the other function is pretty common...the wiki page on [trigonometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) is great!

One more hint?

> $\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A$

Comment: Yes $cos(θ-90) = sin(θ)$ but that doesn't help me resolve it sorry

Comment: @Nicholas you will love the wikipage, trust me...

Comment: Cheers, had a look at the page and it is as good as you say!